# Eigenvalues of a specific Hankel matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, fourier-transform, hankel-matrices

I have an $\frac{N}{2} \times \frac{N}{2}$ matrix $G$ with entries given by

\begin{equation}
G_{ij} = \frac{1}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{N}(i+j-\frac{3}{2}))}, \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; 1 \le i,j \le \frac{N}{2},
\end{equation}

where $N$ is an even integer. By the Fourier transformation the matrix elements can be expressed as

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
G_{ij} &= \mathrm{Im} \left[\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \exp\left(\mathrm{i}\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{N}\left(i+j-\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) \right]\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \sin\left[\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{N}\left(i+j-\frac{3}{2}\right)\right].
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Another way to write the entries is as an integral:

\begin{equation}
G_{ij} = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\frac{i+j-3/2}{N}-1}}{1+x} \mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}

Is it possible to find a closed-form expression for the following quantities:

(i) the eigenvalues of $G$ or even its full eigendecomposition?

(ii) $\mathrm{Tr}(G^k)$, for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (in order to determine, e.g., $\mathrm{Tr}(\log(G))$)?

Comment: In other words, $$G_{ij} = \frac1{\sin(\frac{\pi}{N}(i+j-\frac32))}.$$

Comment: That is correct. The entries can also be written as

$$ G_{ij} = \mathrm{Im} \left[ \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \exp\left(\mathrm{i} \frac{\pi(2n+1)}{N} (i+j-3/2)\right) \right]  $$

My idea was to use the Fourier transformation to obtain the eigendecomposition.

Comment: @Marc -- apologies, my answer was mistaken, I have deleted it.